# SaS loop through single dataset

Tags: loops, dataset, sas

I am not rocket science with SaS, but I would like to try and do the same in SaS as in Java.

Say I have a SaS dataset, and I want to go through each record, one by one, and then compare the value gathered from the iteration to a final number.

In Java it would be to loop over an array that in this case would be the same as the whole bunch of data from one single column of the SaS dataset.

The example is the following:

I have a list of account balances, and I want to check if the current balance on the iteration is higher than the previously maximum stored before, and if so, store it, and keep looping until I store the account with the highest balance.

I know that this can be done with the SQL max, but I would like to know how to iterate over the SaS dataset, though I will also appreciate any valid SQL answer.

The SaS dataset would look like this.

```
acct_number            owner_name            acct_balance
0123456789             name1                 12000
1234567890             name2                 16000
2345678901             name3                 14000
```

But I am only interested in `acct_balance` column.

As a code example, in Java it would be like this.

```
int[] acct_balances = new int[8];
int[0] = 10000;
int[1] = 12000;
int[2] = 11000;
int[3] = 16000;
int[4] = 14000;
int[5] = 5000;
int[6] = 16000;
int[7] = 15000;
int max_balance = 0;
int max_balance_position = 0;

int iteration_position = 0;
int maximum_position = acct_balances.length;

do {
    if (acct_balances[iteration_position] > max_balance) {
      max_balance = acct_balances[iteration_position];
      max_balance_position = iteration_position;
    }
  iteration_position ++;
} while(iteration_position < maximum_position);
```

In the end, the output will be `max_balance = 16000` and `max_balance_position = 3`

This code goes through each and every value on the array, but how to translate this code into SaS? Can anyone help me? Very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the form of the SAS dataset? 


Kind of hard to answer without that.

Comment: SAS is typically written using all upper case letters (as opposed to SaaS).  My brain wanted to spaz out everytime I saw it in mixed case like that ;-)

Comment: SAS is correctly spelled in uppercase only - not just typically.  It is not an acronym any longer, and even when it was the A was for a real word (Analysis) not and.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS loops implicitly through each row so you don't need to create a loop. The question is what do you want your output data set to look like. This answer will create a data set with the max alone.

```
data max_acct_balance;
  set have end=eof;
   retain max_acct_balance max_record;
   if acct_balance>max_acct_balance then do;
      max_record=_n_;
      max_acct_balance=acct_balance;
   end;
   if eof then output;
run;
```

Comment: Hi, I have checked the code and it was helpful. I am in owe.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a cnt to your data file

```
proc sql;
     create table test as
            select *, monotonic() as cnt
                   from org_data_set;
quit;
```

and then use:

```
proc sql;
     select bal, cnt-1 as CNT
            from test
                  where cnt = select min(cnt)
                                     from test 
                                          where bal = select max(bal) 
                                                from test;
quit;
```